# glReadPixels(Depth_Component) not working in Android OpenGL ES20

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, depth-buffer

I use the following code to retrieve the depth buffer:

```
FloatBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer
    .allocateDirect(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

GLES20.glReadPixels(pointx, pointy, 1, 1, 
    GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

Problem is, whichever point I am requesting, the pixels is giving me 0.0;

I have enabled the following in `onSurfaceCreated`:

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
GLES20.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

I've been struggling with this issue for days! Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [OpenGL ES 2.0](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) docs, [glReadPixels()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) doesn't support reading the depth buffer. What does [glGetError()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) return?

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I never noticed about this change. Well, no, geterror return 0; BTW, so how can I read the depth buffer from gles2?

Comment: One solution is to do a separate render pass, where you use a shader that fills the color buffer with depth values. This is what I've had to do in the past on DirectX 9.

Comment: Also, maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041682/android-opengl-es-framebuffer-objects-rendering-to-texture

Comment: @Martin Stone - I did check out the link you referenced. I'm trying to pick points in 3D, and obviously can't use depth buffer. Can you explain how to send the depth buffer to the color buffer for use? Thank you!